# Trying to use Apach2 and phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, apache2

I installed apache2, php5,... Using the following command

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5  libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mysql
```

and phpmyadmin using the following command

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Every time I try to access to the phpmyadmin interface I got the following error

```
Not Found

The requested URL /phpmyadmin was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

Anyone can help ??

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems something went wrong with the package installation. Please try to reconfigure it with `dpkg-reconfigure -plow phpmyadmin`. If you're asked which webserver to use, make sure you select Apache (or Apache 2.4).

Comment: thank you for your answer. I solved the problem, there were some code lignes to add in the Apache config file.

Comment: You shouldn't manually modify the configuration when using the package manager; for once it confuses the package manager if you ever remove, reinstall, or update the application. It's best to let the package manager manage the configuration itself. Certainly, it would do something similar to what you've done manually, but now your changes could get wiped out on a software update. Anyway, glad you got it going regardless.